# How do I set the FailoverBehavior for RavenDB globally

Tags: asp.net, .net, ravendb

Currently, I have something like this everywhere in my ASP.NET MVC site wherever I need to connect to RavenDB.

```
using (var ds = new DocumentStore { Url = urlBase }.Initialize())
            {
                ds.Conventions.FailoverBehavior = FailoverBehavior.ReadFromAllServers;
            }
```

Is there a way that I can set the FailoverBehavior globally, like perhaps in the web.config, so that I don't have to do this every time I create a new instance of the DocumentStore?

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be one DocumentStore instance in your application per database (initialized usually from global.asax), you never create one from an MVC controller, so your question never begins...